# Restore default colors (black text on a white background)

Tags: themes, colors

I played around with `elpy` and after following the tutorial, it changed the emacs theme to a black background.

When trying to revert this, I managed to get a white font on a white background persistently after startup :-) .

How do I revert all colour- and theme- settings back to the default emacs theme? I am unable to find any relevant changes in my `.emacs`.

I am using the emacs 25 snapshot.

I used this [turorial](https://realpython.com/blog/python/emacs-the-best-python-editor/)

Comment: I ended up deleting my .emacs.d directory, which I managed to rebuild by hand afterwards. I would still be interested in a less crude solution.

Comment: This sounds very strange. Elpy does not touch faces or themes at all. The guide you link to uses a package called "material theme" - maybe that was the culprit?

Comment: You are right. It most likely was the material-theme, and has nothing to do with elpy. I am still not sure how to uninstall the material-theme cleanly though.

Comment: Remove the respective directory/directories from ~/.emacs.d/elpa/mercuria-theme* and restart Emacs. That should do it.